# Silverlight - Add Ellipses to a canvas dynamically with MVVM

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

I want to add a dynamic number of ellipses to a canvas and set the ellipse position (canvas.top, canvas.left).  I tried binding to an ItemsControl but it each item (ellipse) has a container, so I cant set the ellipses position directly.  I don't want an items container, I just want a canvas that contains ellipses.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - worked for me -- I use it to freely place textblocks on a canvas.

> Re: Re: Positioning Items when Canvas is the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl
>   02-26-2010 7:17 AM |
>
> There is an alternative simpler solution that does work in silverlight 3.

```
 
 <Canvas>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding MyItems}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Canvas>
          <TextBlock Canvas.Left={Binding Left} Canvas.Top={Binding Top} Text={Binding Text} />
        </Canvas>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

> If the MyItems is a list of items that are of a class that has Left, Top and Text public properties, this works fine. I have also tested with Line and Border to draw simple bar graph graphics in silverlight 3.

From the bottom of this post:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/29753/450510.aspx#450510

Combine it with a Silverlight DataTemplateSelector and you can change the objects you draw based on view model properties:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I would say use an `ItemsControl` in conjunction with a `Canvas`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ellipses}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

But in a display of Silverlight suckiness, the `ItemContainerStyle` property does not work on `ItemsControl`. It has *support* in `ItemsControl`, but it's not exposed by `ItemsControl` itself. Instead, it's up to subclasses of `ItemsControl` - such as `ListBox` - to expose it. Oh, and those subclasses have to be provided by Microsoft because the functionality is `protected internal`, so you can't just subclass `ItemsControl` and expose this stuff yourself.  :S

So you could use `ListBox` instead, possibly by subclassing it and changing its item container to something simpler than a `ListBoxItem`. Or you could just use `ListBox` directly and fiddle around until the `ListBoxItem`s look the way you want them to (i.e. not selected).

Comment: So there is no way to get around the itemContainer?

Comment: I just explained how in my post :S